# Probability question based on Heisenberg's uncertainty principle?

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, probability, virtual-particles

Heisenberg's uncertainty principle relates energy and life time $\tau$ of a particle as follow:

$\tau=\frac{\bar{h}}{1+x^2}$

Here energy is approximated as $1+x^2$ where $x$, the velocity of particle, varies from $0$ to $c$.

It means that particles with lower energy will have longer life time.

If I choose a particle at random, what is the probability that it's velocity $x$ will be in the range $[0,v]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uncertainty principle is not about the velocities of particles, it is about [simultaneous measurement of  the two variables.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/uncer.html)

[image: heisen]

It can be used to estimate the lifetime of a decay as [seen here](https://ef.engr.utk.edu/hyperphysics/hbase/quantum/parlif.html)

> suggests that for particles with extremely short lifetimes, there will be a significant uncertainty in the measured energy. The measurment of the **mass energy** of an unstable particle a large number of times gives a distribution of energies called a Lorentzian or a Breit-Wigner distribution.

Note it is the mass of the resonance or high mass particle , as the Higgs for example, that puts limits on the posibility of *simultaneous* measurement of energy and time.

It does not relate to the formulas you use, using the kinetic energy of a particle.

This statement of yours is wrong:

> It means that particles with lower energy will have longer life time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am actually trying to find the energy distribution of virtual particles or velocity distribution i.e. what percentage of virtual particles exist in a given velocity range. Couldn't find any data so I thought may be I can use this relation. Do you have any info about energy distribution of virtual particles?

Comment: vrtual particles are mathematical place holders of quantum numbers, under  the integrals trepresenting interactions, as depicted by Feymnman diagrams http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html. They are off mass shell, and though a four vector describes them the energy there has the limits and form  imposed by the particular integration.. I do not think you can get a percentage of particles, because they are not particles, just  a mathematical trick.