# Energy distribution of virtual particles?

Tags: mass-energy, virtual-particles

I have been trying to find the energy distribution of virtual particles i.e. to know what percentage of virtual particles would lie in a given velocity range.

Couldn't find anything on net and tried using Heisenberg energy-time relation to model it but it turned out to be wrong. [See here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/587711/probability-question-based-on-heisenbergs-uncertainty-principle/587713#587713).

Any help in this matter will be appreciated!

Comment: Virtual particles do not have a velocity. You are not going to understand this until you learn  some real quantum mechanics.

Comment: Please look at equation (2) and preceding arguments in this [article](https://www.epj.org/images/stories/news/2013/epj_d_2a-03-13.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

[Virtual particles](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html) are mathematical place holders of quantum numbers, under the integrals representing interactions, as depicted by Feynman diagrams. A simple example electron electron scattering, the first order diagram.

[image: virt]

> Only lines entering or leaving the diagram represent observable particles. Here two electrons enter, exchange a photon, and then exit. The time and space axes are usually not indicated. The vertical direction indicates the progress of time upward, but the horizontal spacing does not give the distance between the particles.

The intermediate line represents a virtual photon, i.e. it has all the quantum numbers of the photon, except its mass is off mass shell, it can have a mass other than the zero which is the mass of the photon. It is under an integral over the angles of possible scatters, and it has no meaning to ask about its velocity because it is just a mathematical trick.

The same is true in diagrams where the virtual particles are electrons or W or whatever in the table of the standard model. Within the integrals, they would be off mass shell, the four vector representing them taking variable momenta and energies, so no *velocity* could be  calculated.

The energy distribution would depend on mathematics of the particular exact diagram.

Comment: Please look at equation (2) and preceding arguments in this [article](https://www.epj.org/images/stories/news/2013/epj_d_2a-03-13.pdf)

Comment: It is a proposal by a group of theorists, and eq 2 is assumed in order to build up their theory.. There is no contradiction to the virtual described above.

Comment: If they can assume to build their theory upon it can I also use it in same way? They have said "not taking into account a full probability density of the pairs kinetic energy." This is the point from where I want to build my theory. I want to have an approximate probability density of kinetic energy of virtual particles.

Comment: I do not know, as I am just an experimental high energy physicist. Do you know quantum field theory to formulate it as the paper does? if not, your theory will be science fiction. The energy distribution they are talking about is within the virtual integrals, it is the real photon interaction with vacuum loops that feeds the virtual loops.

Comment: I know QFT just enough to understand their article. I just want to know if from the relation between lifetime and energy as given, the probability of finding a particle in given velocity range can be worked out.

Comment: afaik the probability will depend on the particular diagram, i.e. how much energy the photon which is interacting with the vacuum has.. The  relation is a heuristic relation, that happened to allow them to get the connection between classical and quantum numbers, an extra postulate if you want for the quantum mechanical frame.

Comment: I am looking to model the probability based solely on energy-time uncertainty as a starter. The energy corrections for different cases can be worked out later. If you can help/guide/hint with modeling just based on uncertainty relation then it will be really appreciated.

Comment: sorry,I  cannot be of any help. It needs a theorist.

Comment: Really nice answer.